VC++ 2022 redist license terms
Looking to provide the license terms for including Microsoft VC++ 2022 redistributable files with our software, as we've recently upgraded our vc++ version.
We currently just copy the contents of C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\14.40.33807\x64\Microsoft.VC143.CRT into out inno installer but I'm struggling to find any direct statement from Microsoft that this is allowed.
Are we only allowed to include the actual redist installer, located in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\VC\Redist\MSVC\v143\vc_redist.x64.exe?
Anyone know where the licence terms for including the raw *.dll files are located? (or even if this is allowed?)
This is the redist licence terms I've found so far, but they don't directly mention the filenames that may be redistributed.
thanks.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/redistribution#-distributable-code-files-for-visual-studio-2022
